# Ruby integration for Joomla using com_api

Tags: ruby, rest, ruby-on-rails-4, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am creating an application which uses REST API to access web-services of WordPress and Joomla.

I got success to do this with `WordPress` but I am unable to do this with `Joomla-3`.

I want to make a REST API call using `Ruby Net::Http` to access `Joomla` powered site. I want to access content of `Joomla-3` enabled site using REST API. I found [com_api](https://github.com/techjoomla/com_api) but I don't know how to use it.

Please can anyone help me how to connect `Ruby on Rails` and Joomla 3 with each other.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a commercial Joomla package which combines an admin component with an extensible plugin architecture to expand service capabilities. You may refer to may other responses for more information:

[REST API for Joomla 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340885/rest-api-for-joomla-3-0/32706378#32706378)

[How to Install and use joomla rest api step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755023/how-to-install-and-use-joomla-rest-api-step-by-step/32851826#32851826)

A key feature of this extension is that it is built upon the Slim PHP micro-framework in order to take advantage of a robust, standards-compliant service route architecture. This allows Joomla to take care of login authentication and group permissions, while Slim exposes routes for GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc. Another advantage is that Joomla allows for selective activation and permissioning for different web service plugins.

Installation, configuration and API docs can be found here:

http://learn.getcapi.org

For a general product overview, please visit http://getcapi.org.