# Create Web API from joomla With Sites

Tags: android, web-services

I have an website Created with **Joomla**. I have to grab those posted articles and data in my android app through RESTful api.I am an android developer so I'm not much familiar with JOOMLA. I viewed database created by joomla and I found very critical table structure. I am confused how to create RESTful services from that. Can anyone explain briefly step by step What should I do to make RESTful api from that website's database please? Any suggestion, effective links will be much appreciated.

Comment: JOOMLA RESTFUL API FOLLOW THIS EXAMPLE http://www.slideshare.net/coolbung/joomla-rest-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer my answer on the following page for more details: [REST API for Joomla 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340885/rest-api-for-joomla-3-0/32706378#32706378)

Basically, I have built a commercially distributed Joomla API, powered by the Slim micro-framework.

The functionality for querying the database via RESTful JSON API can be built into add-on plugins (I'm actually working on ones for MySQL, MSSQL and possibly even MongoDB).

The advantage here is that you get all the benefits of a slick framework like Slim, with the convenient user management, content management, ACL and 3rd party extensions of Joomla. You also get a control panel to manage tokens, API parameters, rate-limits, etc.

More info here, http://getcapi.org