# Web services to interact between Joomla backend and iOS/Android app

Tags: php, android, ios, web-services, joomla

We just started to develop an app where we need to get some data from a Joomla backend. (Data would be company profiles. Those companies register on the Joomla webiste and the public information gets displayed in our app).

What is the best way to communicate between the app and the Joomla backend? The information from the database just has to be pulled once at the start of the app and maybe by manual refreshing.

So far I have read about REST API and SOAP as web-services. I played a bit around with examples from the internet but wasn't really successful yet. So could one of you give a simple explanation and a small example for the interaction between Joomla backend and an Android app e.g.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a pre-packaged solution to turn Joomla 3.5/3.6 into a Mobile Back-end as a Service (MBaSS) you may want to explore cAPI Core REST API.

https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/capi-core-rest-api

Please note that this is a commercial plugin which I developed. If you are OK with that, you may read on here for more information from a previously answered question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32706378/5361267

API Documentation can be found here:

http://learn.getcapi.org

Swagger UI Docs:

https://demo1.getcapi.io/api-docs

To answer your specific question about profiles, this extension will allow you to read and update profile data associated with any user. In addition to the built-in profile fields, the profile creation methods allow you to create and populate unique profile keys. While these might not be visible in the joomla interface (because they have to be defined in XML as well), they can be queried / updated remotely as needed.

PUT /user/profile/{id}

https://demo1.getcapi.io/api-docs#!/User/putUserProfileById